# What is the C# Arcobject I must use in order to set programatically the SQL Query of an LYR file?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, oracle-spatial

I would like to change programatically the SQL Query of a LYR file. I'm developping in C# using ArcObject.

Actually I'm able to get an instance of IWorkspaceFactory from an opened layer with this code :

```
  IDataLayer dataLayer = (IDataLayer)lyrFile.Layer;       
  IDatasetName datasetName = (IDatasetName)dataLayer.DataSourceName;
  IWorkspaceFactory wsFactory = datasetName.WorkspaceName.WorkspaceFactory;
```

But from here I'm stuck. I don't know how to access to the SQL Query. I've read that with ISQLWorkspace I could maybe do something. But, really I'm not sure at all.

The goal here is to create multiple copies of a layer file (lyr), changing only the SQL Query slightly. I need to do so because I do not have enough functionnalities within the "Definition Query" tab to implements different variations of my SQL query.

[image: The Sql Query that I'm looking to change programmatically.]

Comment: What do you mean by the SQL-query for the layer? If you mean the definition-query you may set it via `IFeatureLayerDefinition.DefinitionExpression`

Comment: I have just added an image in my question in order to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: I can do slightly change within the WHERE clause part of my SQL with IFeatureLayerDefinition.DefinitionExpression. But if I want to do a LEFT OTER JOIN, I have to change the SQL Query "under the hood".

Comment: You *cannot* change the SQL query used by ArcGIS to include a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` without using a view which includes such a join

Answer (score 4):

Arcobjects has two interfaces to join multiple FeatureClasses and (or) Tables:

1. Query tables (IQueryDef)
2. RelQueryTables

The result of your join can be added to the map as a Layer if the result has a geometry column.

Make sure to read this **[Page](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/a3af4514-7a6a-4c05-b26d-942d717d09a3.htm)** to check the differences of two and select the one that suites your needs